# Bring forward matching row values on a group-by max() call (to know values corresponding to max value of a specific column)

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to find out, for each year represented in a data table, what the max daily frequency for an event was each year and what day it occurred on. I can get the max value by year like so:

```
dt[, .N, by = DATE][, .(max(N)), by=format(DATE, "%Y")]
```

But how can I bring forward the complete `DATE` (not just year) that matches this max value?

Here's what I tried:

```
dt[, .N, by=DATE][which(N==max(N)), .(max(N), d:=DATE),by=format(DATE, "%Y")]
```

which certainly doesn't even look like it should work, and doesn't, per this error message:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(dt[, .N, by = DATE], which(N == max(N)), .(max(N),  : 
  'by' appears to evaluate to column names but isn't c() or key(). Use by=list(...) if you can. Otherwise, by=eval(format(DATE, "%Y")) should work. This is for efficiency so data.table can detect which columns are needed.
```

I see how I can easily backtrack to `dt` and grab the rows corresponding to the max, but I'd like to do it better than that. **Is there a way to do this with subset selections, as above?**

Apologies if I missed an SO post on this, but couldn't find anything.

Here's a sample of `dt`:

```
> dput(dt[sample(1:600000, size = 500), DATE])
structure(c(16091, 15909, 15987, 16509, 16294, 16610, 16297, 
15898, 15928, 15949, 16351, 16203, 16215, 15799, 16506, 15931, 
16091, 15825, 15860, 15814, 15975, 16233, 16108, 16590, 15700, 
16019, 16178, 16287, 16730, 16366, 16678, 16010, 16157, 16116, 
15794, 16157, 16010, 16171, 16721, 16640, 16302, 15939, 15928, 
16325, 15837, 15848, 15730, 15828, 16414, 16431, 16389, 16003, 
16444, 16255, 16268, 16226, 16205, 15765, 16060, 15938, 16376, 
15934, 15871, 16163, 16568, 15899, 16597, 16160, 16538, 15703, 
16002, 16371, 16019, 16138, 16091, 15874, 16298, 16086, 15753, 
16310, 16209, 15843, 16307, 16472, 16319, 16519, 15743, 16480, 
16323, 16674, 16147, 16013, 15986, 16616, 16480, 16494, 16030, 
16614, 16447, 15991, 15977, 15884, 16707, 16614, 16470, 16193, 
16453, 16342, 16109, 15731, 16321, 16421, 15974, 16578, 16718, 
16183, 15721, 15854, 16470, 16368, 16399, 16433, 16721, 16624, 
16514, 15918, 16370, 15910, 16308, 15973, 16579, 16606, 16192, 
16445, 16671, 15927, 15958, 16140, 15957, 16623, 16416, 15852, 
15913, 16190, 15930, 16420, 15808, 15862, 16507, 16447, 16109, 
15732, 16700, 15911, 16183, 16215, 16584, 15840, 16628, 16138, 
16500, 16477, 16184, 16510, 16374, 16668, 16278, 16642, 16713, 
16324, 16200, 16255, 15960, 16395, 15869, 16282, 16736, 16164, 
16416, 16496, 16565, 15741, 16308, 16441, 16607, 16190, 15938, 
16045, 15758, 16219, 16165, 16357, 16353, 16731, 16063, 15740, 
16220, 16522, 15864, 15922, 16223, 15806, 16660, 16471, 15954, 
16369, 15750, 15957, 16156, 16367, 16654, 16165, 16109, 15863, 
16204, 15929, 15812, 15987, 16275, 16552, 15741, 15906, 15929, 
16295, 15974, 15749, 15830, 15892, 16266, 16208, 15793, 15768, 
15721, 16707, 15903, 16624, 16552, 16695, 16116, 16573, 16344, 
16452, 16539, 16195, 15851, 16140, 16152, 15736, 16179, 15846, 
16363, 16404, 16522, 16723, 16021, 16232, 16081, 16206, 16183, 
15920, 16543, 15989, 15974, 16212, 16396, 16473, 16502, 16532, 
16326, 15882, 16607, 15848, 15954, 16419, 15752, 16030, 16429, 
16222, 16213, 16626, 16049, 16738, 16256, 16198, 16599, 15727, 
16707, 16433, 15863, 16145, 16188, 15862, 15707, 16475, 16130, 
15887, 16647, 15974, 16221, 15773, 16059, 16662, 16250, 15689, 
15753, 15833, 16365, 16646, 16366, 16130, 16712, 15859, 16480, 
15983, 16377, 16091, 16121, 15821, 16505, 16018, 16254, 15937, 
16322, 16490, 15899, 16377, 16319, 16262, 16215, 16005, 16318, 
16488, 16350, 16275, 16723, 16616, 16593, 15918, 16264, 15897, 
15931, 16204, 16603, 16192, 16377, 15837, 16737, 16466, 16271, 
15804, 15987, 16622, 16634, 16227, 16297, 16597, 16232, 16393, 
15842, 15999, 15716, 16092, 16080, 16553, 16068, 16129, 16012, 
16383, 16150, 16611, 16602, 16254, 15728, 15958, 15827, 16111, 
16097, 16112, 16648, 16510, 16417, 16021, 16660, 15793, 16016, 
16188, 16034, 16415, 16270, 16728, 16153, 16028, 16286, 16731, 
15905, 15710, 16208, 16300, 16522, 16062, 16310, 16535, 16111, 
16682, 15957, 16051, 16597, 16063, 15828, 16658, 16213, 16262, 
15814, 15912, 16115, 15716, 15976, 16665, 16723, 15766, 15825, 
16682, 16547, 16402, 16486, 16085, 16231, 16126, 16398, 15762, 
16563, 15796, 15993, 15943, 16020, 15727, 16671, 16044, 15921, 
16511, 15787, 16128, 16376, 16502, 15751, 16317, 16444, 16032, 
15839, 16588, 15780, 15926, 16722, 16225, 16523, 16450, 16661, 
16702, 16223, 15977, 16586, 16221, 16252, 15853, 16309, 15838, 
16505, 16143, 16526, 15980, 15970, 15718, 16713, 16021, 16546, 
16469, 16452, 15729, 16309, 16543, 16386, 16554, 16349, 16595, 
16499, 16359, 16322, 16547, 16415, 16112, 15898, 16008, 16275, 
15975, 16197, 15740, 15959, 16346, 16364, 16522), class = "Date")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply subset `.SD` with `which.max(N)`?

```
require(data.table)
data.table(x)[, .N, by=x][, .SD[which.max(N)], by=year(x), .SDcols=1:2]
#    year          x N
# 1: 2014 2014-01-21 4
# 2: 2013 2013-09-26 4
# 3: 2015 2015-03-28 4
# 4: 2012 2012-12-26 1
```

Once you're familiar with `.SD`, most operations just use base R functions.

---

On your tries: The general form of data.table is to *susbet* rows in `i`, *and then* compute `j` grouped by `by`. So, you can't provided the condition in `i` and group in `by`. And `.(d := DATE)` isn't valid syntax at all.

Please read the [vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started). These things are all in there.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with:

```
DT[, Y := year(DATE)]

DT[,
  copy(.SD)[, n := .N , by=DATE][which.max(n)]
, by=Y]


      Y       DATE n
1: 2014 2014-01-21 4
2: 2013 2013-09-26 4
3: 2015 2015-03-28 4
4: 2012 2012-12-26 1
```

I'm hoping there is a better way. I created `Y` because data.table currently doesn't allow columns to be used inside `j` if any transformation of them appears in `by`.

Comment: thank you for this suggestion. I even modified it a bit by setting .SDcols since I don't need everything. I was interested to see that you have to add column Y. I tried substituting into your expression by=year(DATE), but as you already know, that doesn't work. Do you happen to know why?

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you this, but it does not seem after all that the code you provided is working. Actually as I tried it out I noticed that it was not actually returning the date associated with the max. I will add a more complete data set to the question so folks can try this out in more detail, but it seems to just return the max date rather than the date associated with the max value, strangely enough.

Comment: @sunny I think I found my mistake: should've used `which.max(n)` not `which.max(.N)`.